# Fibre bundles and good pairs

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

Consider a fibre bundle $E\rightarrow B$. I was wondering when we can say that the pair $(E,B)$ is a good pair? By a good pair $(A,X)$ I mean two spaces $X\subset A$ such that $X$ is closed and is a deformation retract of some neighbourhood of it in $A$.

In the smooth category, we can assume all spaces to be CW-complexes and hence if we can show that $B$ is a subcomplex of $E$, then we have that $(E,B)$ is a CW-pair and in particular a good pair. I feel like this is the case, but i'm not entirely sure (my knowledge of CW-complexes is not very good, but the answer to the question [Does the total space of a fibre bundle have the homotopy type of a CW complex if the base and the fibers have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/285351/452113) does make it feel plausible).

However, I would also be interested in the more general case where we work in the category of topological spaces and have no access to smooth structures and hence cannot resort to CW complexes.

My interest comes from the relation between reduced (co)homology of the quotient space $E/B$ and the relative (co)homology of the pair $(E,B)$.

Comment: How do you define a *good pair*?

Comment: Are you assuming you have a section?

Comment: @Tyrone Like Hatcher and most other authors I think. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Well think about the covering projection $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$. This is a fibre bundle. On the other hand, $S^1$ admits no embedding into $\mathbb{R}$ (as the image of a section of $p$ or otherwise). Its image under a putative embedding would be a connected compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so would be an interval. But $S^1$ is not contractible. Thus the bundle fails to give you even a pair, good or otherwise.

Comment: The point is that unless you have a section, these neither space is a subspace of the other so it doesn't make sense to talk about good pairs.

Comment: Yes, true. One does indeed need a section. So yes, I am assuming there to be one ;) @Tyrone and what in the case where we require all spaces (also the fibre) to be "nice" spaces, e.g. (path)connected?

Comment: I think in general the notion of 'fibre bundle' alone is lacking. What you are looking for is rather a 'sectioned bundle' (ie. a bundle with a distinguished section). This is easily corrected, but still insufficient. For instance, take any degenerately-based pointed space $X$ and let $s:B\rightarrow B\times X$, $b\mapsto (b,\ast)$, be a section of the projection $pr_B:B\times X\rightarrow B$. The section gives you a pair $(B\times X,B)$, but it is not 'good' by the assumption on the basepoint of $X$.

Comment: The point is that you might as well restrict to 'non-degenerately sectioned fibrations', which you might define to be fibrations $p:E\rightarrow B$ paired with a distinguished section $s:B\rightarrow E$ which turns $(E,B)$ into a good pair. One you've done this your question seems fairly straightforwards ;)

Comment: So i should conclude that there is not really a general sufficient condition in either the topological or the smooth category?

Comment: @NDewolf In the smooth category, if the base is compact then you do have a good pair. This follows from the much more general fact that a smooth submanifolds of a smooth manifold form a good pair. If you have boundary, there is going to be some tameness condition near the boundary.

Comment: Oh i see, I hadnt thought about it before, but indeed, the tubular neighbourhood theorem (or similar statements) give rise to an NDR pair. I should have noted that earlier...

Comment: Yes it is very useful, for example in surgery theory one needs that it gives a good pair so it has HEP.